# How to insert 200 rows in DynamoDB table in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have used batchWriteItem() to insert the data in batch but it allows 25 array items to be inserted. 
I have more then 200 records at a time to be inserted. Is there any way or any technique to get it done. 
I don't wanted to use AWS Data Pipeline. 
I also don't want to do it like to split the array into the parts of 25 array items and then insert every part in one time by calling batchWriteItem() 4 times if we have 200 array items.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated the BatchWriteItems request has a limit of 25 items in a single request, other then AWS Data Pipeline there is unfortunately no alternative.

Assuming you've provisioned enough write throughput, you should be able to speed things up significantly by splitting those 200+ records between multiple threads/processes/hosts and pushing them to the database in parallel.

Comment: I have provisioned enough write throughput, For processes/threads I have an option of Gearman Job Server but If I use Gearman I'll not be able to manage the Unprocessed items.